# Weird pagination issue

Tags: expressionengine

This is related to this forum post regarding Solspace’s super search http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/14436/ but since I’m having the same issue with EE’s channel entry loop I’m double-posting here.
My debug page is here

```
http://216.243.140.102/products/pagination_debug
```

, code is a barebones:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="static" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data" limit="2" paginate="bottom"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{paginate}
<p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Every pagination link looks like this

```
http://216.243.140.102/S=3e4a8ada2d96477c46a1a7388370eb27992550a7/products/pagination_debug/P6
```

with an added S=3e4a8ada2d96477c46a1a7388370eb27992550a7

Any ideas? I’m completely stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto *Admin - >  Security and Session Preferences* and make sure your **User Session Type** is set to **Cookies Only**

Alternatively it may be overridden in your config.php

```
$config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
```

Comment: Cheers mate, was already heading in that direction. You made my day!